# Forcing Android Media Player in HTC Evo 3D to show 3D

Tags: android, 3d, android-mediaplayer, stereo-3d, htcsense

I want to force the Evo 3D Mediaplayer to show any videos as 3D. The problem is that the HTC Evo 3D is said to be becoming 3D with FPA SEI flag on mp4 file. Is there any way to introduce that flag programmatically?

I want to find where it is overridden and turn it off by hand. I tried to figure out where it is read in the Android media player( http://www.netmite.com/android/mydroid/frameworks/base/media/java/android/media/MediaPlayer.java ); however, I couldn't found. My guess is the HTC is implemented another media player which looks for SEI FPA flag in mp4 header.

Is there anybody who can help me with this situation?

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to upload your 3D SBS video to Youtube, and then ask Youtube to change it to 3D. When it's done, wait for 20 minutes and then view your video in 3D on Youtube from your Evo 3D. If it works, then just go ahead and download it from the Youtube website using an internet download manager. Now, if you put that video on your SD card, it should play directly in 3D mode.